# How large are iptables byte counters?

Tags: iptables

In other words at what point do they overflow and reset to zero. The iptables manual appears not to say. Are they 32bit of 64bit?

Answer (score 3):

See [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables):

```
The counters are 64-bit and are thus not expected to overflow ;)
```